# Using php with an oracle db would this be sufficient validation

Tags: php, oracle, validation

I'm new to using oracle but i'd assume validating everything should be the same in php with most any db.

I already have my js validation on the front end so i'm not in need of that.

here's my form:

```
<br/><br/>
<form method="post">
<legend>Log In</legend><br/>
<label for='email' >Email Address*:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br/><br/>
<label for="password">Password*:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required><br/><br/>
<input type='button' name='login' id='login' value='Login' />
</form>
```

ajax layer:

```
if (isset($_GET['email']) && $_GET['email'] != '' && isset($_GET['password']) && $_GET['password'] != '') {

    // todo: change their connection string to become their Oracle user.
    $shopper = new Shopper($_GET['email']);
    $token = $shopper->login($_GET['password']);

    if (isset($token) && $token != '') {
        echo json_encode($token);
    }
}
```

php api layer:

```
//both parameters are required, so make sure they were passed-in
if(!isset($_GET['email'])) {
    die('Must pass \'email\' through the URL');
}
if(!isset($_GET['password'])) {
    die('Must pass \'password\' through the URL');
}

//instantiate a new Shopper object for the email address that was passed-in
$foo = new Shopper($_GET['email'])
or die('Could not create the Shopper object using the \'email\' passed-in');

//token will be null if the password for the user is incorrect
$token = $foo->login($_GET['password']);

//thus what is echoed here will be a null JSON array
echo json_encode($token);
```

Does everything look solid? Any advice or help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Like you said, the database used shouldn't matter, especially since no database seems to be (directly) used in your code. So basically the question is not really clear to me.

Comment: Its not going to stop a script brute forcing, also when correct the API returns json, for continuity it should return json on fail (instead of die())

Comment: Considering js validation: js validation is no validation. It's a UI feature to help the user. It won't do anything regarding protection.

Comment: Parameters are filled out and verified in the DB is what i'm looking for, is this sufficient and is there anything else i can do to ensure the credentials are correct in the db and the user is who they say they are?

Comment: Hope that makes more sense @GolezTrol

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, can you elaborate on that part, which section are you talking about? email, password or when i'm instantiating the Shopper class?